# How to add Google Tag Manager code via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant site with common header where I am currently injecting the Google Analytics code via following simple JavaScript.

```
if(window.location.href.startsWith("https://docs.domain1.com"))
{
   loadGroupDocsCloudResources('UA-xxxxxxx-x');
}
function addGoogleTrackingCode(trackingCode)
{
  var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=" + trackingCode;
    s.setAttribute('async','');
    $("head").append(s);

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', trackingCode);
}
```

This works fine, however, we have now defined GTM containers for each site and therefore need to update the code to insert the same.

I have so far tried to add the code by storing the GTM scripts in 2 variables and injected to head & body using the JavaScript's append command, that has not worked.

Please note, there are 2 parts of the GTM scripts, following has to go in head.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxxx');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Following has to go in body.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-xxxxx"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Is there a way to handle this dynamically? Means, I want to put 3 or more sets of the GTM scripts for different sites via JavaScript?

Comment: Not an answer, but I still want to point out that it's pointless to inject a noscript tag via Javascript, so you might as well drop the second part.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I still need to dynamically add the noscript to multi-site setup built on JSP. Do you have any suggestion how to add it, if not to use JavaScript.

Comment: You can include the Google Tag Manager script the same way like you did for gtag.
1. loadscript: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=CONTAINERID&l=dataLayer
2. after the script is loaded initialize by calling gtag('gtm.start', new Date());